# How can I specify the default image viewer in mailcap?

Tags: mutt

I have most of my home directory dot files shared across my home and work systems, each running a different version of Ubuntu.

I'm looking for a way to specify the default image viewer for each system in ~/.mailcap, so when it's invoked by mutt, the correct image viewer will start.

My current work-around is to put the following in ~/.mailcap ...

```
image/*; viewimage %s; test=test -n "$DISPLAY";
```

... where **viewimage** is a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
hostname=`hostname`

if [ $hostname == 'work-host' ]; then
    imageviewer=geeqie
elif [ $hostname == 'home-host' ]; then
    imageviewer=ristretto
fi

$imageviewer $1
```

Any suggestions to avoid this workaround are appreciated.

Comment: the problem with xdg-open is that it launches the relevant application and exit immediately. When xdg-open will exit, the mail reader will then consider that the job is done and remove the attachement that was stored for viewing (most of the time in /tmp) and that before the real viewer was launched. The viewer will then say that it can't find the file to be viewed.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is nice and lets you keep all the dotfiles on version control, so why change it? :-)

If you run either of the major desktop environments, invoke `xdg-open` instead? Is is the equivalent of double clicking a file in the file browser.